# Switch between different schemas in the same JNDI

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jndi

Is there a way we can switch between different schemas in the same JNDI dynamically? For example, if schema1, schema2 are two schemas in the same database(the JNDI is configured for this database), how do we switch between schema1 and schema2?

I know how to use AbstractRoutingDataSource. But I do not want to use JDBC connection parameters in my application. Instaed, I want to configure a single JNDI (without specifying the property 'currentSchema') and be able to switch between the different schemas in that JNDI dynamically.

Can this be done?

Comment: Uhm, just prefix the tablenames with the corresponding schema...

Comment: i am talking about switching between schemas. why would I want to prefix table names?

Comment: I do not get the problem. Say you have a table `A` in schema `s1` and schema `s2`, you want to dynamically decide which schema to use?

Comment: yes. The JNDI name for both the schemas will be the same because they are both in the same database. How do I switch between the two schemas?